# Set all new product automatically to be virtual products by default in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

Is there a way to make all products to be virtual products by default? So if one adds new product then it is automatically set to "virtual"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this below code in your current active theme functions.php file

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'enable_virtual_option' );
function enable_virtual_option(){

?>

        <script>
            (function($){
                $('input[name=_virtual]').prop('checked', true);

            })(jQuery);
        </script>

        <?php

}
```

Comment: This works, but this doesn't determine if it's for new posts only. So the preselection happens on already configured products as well. One solution could be adding `$('body').hasClass('post-new-php')` into the JavaScript code.